# How to use OWL/RDL to represent and query a connected graph?

Tags: prolog, owl, ontology, knowledge-management, protege

In PROLOG you can represent and query a connect graph, as in this tutorial:

```
http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html
```

How would you do this using an OWL/RDL tool such as Protégé (http://protege.stanford.edu/)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this by using a semantic reasoner, such as [Racer Pro](http://www.sts.tu-harburg.de/~r.f.moeller/racer/) (non-free) and [Pellet](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/) (free, open source if under used in an open source project).

[This wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_reasoner) gives a comprehensive list of reasoners available with a comparison table.